# Column in Select calculation but I don't want it in the group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, pivot

I have a query which sums a column if the `datediff` on two other columns is less than a value, but I don't want to group by the columns in the calculation. Can someone tell me the best way to do this?  I thought of a nested query or using pivot but neither gives what I want.  Here is the sql:

```
SELECT 
    Col7, 
    Col8, 
    Case when datediff (dd,col3,col4) < 30 then Sum(Col2) ELSE 0 END as [30days], 
    Case when datediff (dd,col3,col4) < 60 then Sum(Col2) ELSE 0 END as [60days] 
FROM Table 
Group BY 
    Col7, Col8
```

I do not want to group by `Col3` or `Col4`.

Comment: Are you familiar with common table expressions?  Without seeing how the underlying data is structured, I'm thinking that will be your best option.  Can you provide some details on the data?

Comment: `sum(case when datediff(dd,col3,col4) < 30 then col2 else 0 end)`

Comment: could you add the Table structure and specify the primary key as well as some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Expressions that are not encapsulated within an aggregate function must be included in the GROUP BY Clause at the end of the SQL statement*

When using the following logic

```
Case when datediff (dd,col3,col4) < 30 then Sum(Col2) ELSE 0 END as [30days],
```

This is not considered as an aggregate function that Col7 and Col8 can grouped by.  Replacing this logic with

```
SUM(Case when datediff (dd,col3,col4) < 30 then Col2 ELSE 0 END) as [30days],
```

Will fix the issue

Read more in this [Group by MSDN artcle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  The MSDN article was also helpful.

Comment: I your issue was solved you have [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). If no give us a feedback

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your SUM() outside of the Case..when
Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Col7, 
    Col8, 
    SUM(Case when datediff (dd,col3,col4) < 30 then Col2 ELSE 0 END) as [30days], 
    SUM(Case when datediff (dd,col3,col4) < 60 then Col2 ELSE 0 END) as [60days] 
FROM Table 
Group BY 
    Col7, Col8
```

Comment: Thanks.  No idea what I was thinking.